# excel VBA - return cell value that includes the escaping apostrophe

Tags: vba, excel

Given two cells with contents `'=Foo` and `=Foo`, getting the properties `.Value`,`.Value2`, `.Text`, `.Formula` all give me `=Foo` for both ranges.

How do I include the escaping apostrophe so that I get `'=Foo` when returning the cell value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.PrefixCharacter` to get the hidden apostrophe.

Like this: `Debug.Print Range("A1").PrefixCharacter`

---

Depending on what your trying to do with it, this [Microsoft Post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192891) might be helpful.

---

Full Example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wks.Range("A1")

    If Not rng.HasFormula Then
        If rng.PrefixCharacter <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Cell value is: " & rng.PrefixCharacter & rng.Text
        Else
            MsgBox "No prefix value in cell " & rng.Address
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```